# How to add ads at random position in recyclerview having progressbar at bottom?

Tags: android

I have an app which contain recyclerview and progressbar at bottom when i scroll to end of recyclerview it sends server request for more data which is working fine but problem is that i want to add ads between recyclerview at random position. How do i add this in recyclerview at random position.

code:-

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return contacts.get(position) == null ? VIEW_TYPE_LOADING : VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == 0) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.item_recycler_view_row, parent, false);
        return new UserViewHolder(view);
    } else if (viewType == 1) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.item_loading, parent, false);
        return new LoadingViewHolder(view);
    } else {

    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof UserViewHolder) {
        Contact contact = contacts.get(position);
        UserViewHolder userViewHolder = (UserViewHolder) holder;
        userViewHolder.phone.setText(contact.getEmail());
        userViewHolder.email.setText(contact.getPhone());
    } else if (holder instanceof LoadingViewHolder) {
        LoadingViewHolder loadingViewHolder = (LoadingViewHolder) holder;
        loadingViewHolder.progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contacts == null ? 0 : contacts.size();
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your need try it now

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter, you first need to override `getItemViewType()`, for example:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (contacts.get(position) == null)
        return VIEW_TYPE_LOADING;
    else if (position % 5 == 0)
        return AD_TYPE;
    else {
        return VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
    }
}
```

After that onCreateViewHolder, inflate a different view according to the type like this:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View view = null;
    if (viewType == AD_TYPE) {
        View adView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.native_ads, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolderAdMob(adView);
    } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new UserViewHolder(view);
    }else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_LOADING) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.item_loading, viewGroup, false);
        return new LoadingViewHolder(view);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Native ads xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

AdViewHolder class

```
public static class ViewHolderAdMob extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public AdView mAdView;
    public ViewHolderAdMob(View view) {
        super(view);
        mAdView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

Also Don't forget to change `getItemCount()` accordingly: `return contacts.size()+ (contacts.size() % 5)`

Comment: Hey i have data, progressbar at bottom and now i want to add a View in between recyclerview

Comment: I want to add a view in between recyclerview ..........and progressbar at bottom is already implemented

Comment: But where is progress bar

Comment: which library you are using for  **ads**

Comment: Akhilesh i have recyclerview with some data from server and when i scroll up a progressbar at bottom will be shown which also send request to server for more data which is working fine but i want another view which will contain ads in between recyclerview.....

Comment: wait to give me a min I'll  the code according to your requirement.

Comment: make sure progress bar always remain at bottom

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150176/discussion-between-akhilesh-patil-and-niraj).